# How do i match text after a specific character?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a url that looks like this:

```
http://mysite/#/12345
```

How do I retrieve the text using regex after the /#/ which is essentially a token that I would like to use elsewhere in my javascript application?

Thanks.

Comment: Are there any `substring` or `indexOf` mathods in JavaScript?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need regex here, just `String#substr` using `String#indexOf`:

```
var s = 'http://mysite/#/12345';
var p ='/#/'; // search needle
var r= s.substr(s.indexOf(p) + p.length);
//=> 12345
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with [JavaScript String methods](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_string.asp).

```
var str='http://mysite/#/12345';
alert(str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/#/")+3));
```

---

You can try with [String's`match()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) method as well that uses regex expression.

Just get the matched group from index 1 that is captured by enclosing inside the parenthesis `(...)`

```
var str='http://mysite/#/12345';
alert(str.match(/\/#\/(.*)$/)[1]);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let the browser do it for you

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://mysite/#/12345";
alert(parser.hash.substring(2));  //This is just to remove the #/ at the start of the string
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gibble/uvhqa4yv/

Answer (score -1):

Using the browser to parse the URL and getting the hash would probably be most reliable and would work with any valid URL

```
var url = 'http://mysite/#/12345';
var ele = document.createElement('a');

ele.href = url;

var result = ele.hash.slice(2);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/5ewodtdm/)

or you can just split and pop it

```
var result = url.split('#/').pop();
```